# How to create an event calendar in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I want to do Event/Scheduler calendar in asp.net MVC. So far I've written this code for the database table in [image], but something doesn't work.

The controller code :

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

       public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        var events = db.MedicationTrackers.ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

and the View-Index code

```
@model IEnumerable<LICENTA.Database.MedicationTracker>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<scripts src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></scripts>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var events = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/MedicationTrackers/GetEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(i,v){ //i=index v=value
                    events.push({
                        title: v.IdMember,
                        description: v.IdMedication,
                        start: moment(v.Start),
                        end: v.Stop != null? moment(v.End):null,
                        status: v.Status
                    })

                })
                GenerateCalendar(events);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error occured!!")
            }
                })
            })


        function GenerateCalendar(events) {
            $('calender').fullCalendar('destroy'); //clear first
            $('calender').fullCalendar({
                contentheight: 400,
                defaultdate: new date(),
                timeformat: 'h(:mn)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month, basicweek, basicday, agenda'
                },
                eventlimit: true,
                eventcolor: '#378006',
                events: events
}}

</script>
```

When I run the project the ajax error appear. I tried to test just the calendar to see if it works but it does not appear on the page.

Comment: What ajax error?

Comment: if you get an error, tell us what it says!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `calender` is not an html element. You need to add a `div` to your view with an id:

```
<div id="calendar"><div>
```

And update your javascript:

```
    function GenerateCalendar(events) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy'); //clear first
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                contentheight: 400,
                defaultdate: new date(),
                timeformat: 'h(:mn)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month, basicweek, basicday, agenda'
                },
                eventlimit: true,
                eventcolor: '#378006',
                events: events 
            });
     }
```